# Unable to read serial data from Raspberry Pico

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

My Pico developed sudden problem of not sending data to serial monitor. I can write to the pico via the Serial Port but i can't receive the data sent by the Pico.

I have tried both Micropython,CircuitPython,C/C++  on all GPIO UART pins, Tried to use different cables, but all are giving similar results.
Currently am using FTDI FT232RL USB cable, yellow cable connected to physical pin 6, Orange cable connected to physical pin 7 and both GND connected together.
Below is my micropython piece of code

```
uart = UART(1, baudrate=115200, tx=Pin(4), rx=Pin(5))

txData = 'CDM\n'.encode('utf-8')
while True:
    uart.write(txData)
    data = uart.read()
    if data:   
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: *"Currently am using FTDI FT232RL USB cable"* -- That's an ambiguous (if not inaccurate) description.  You need more than just a *"cable"*;  there has to be a converter chip.  You need a serial converter with a TTL interface, rather than RS-232, for your board.  Note that some of these serial converters label "receive" and "transmit" pins according to the host side, whereas others label per the target side.  I always use a voltmeter to verify the function of the pins.  An input pin (to the host) is likely to be floating at ground (or logic low), and an output pin should  idle at a logic high.

Comment: I have exact same problem: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/558656/raspberry-pi-pico-can-read-from-ftdi-dongle-but-cant-write
I have switched to a different port and it started to work.
Now it has happened again on the new port, so it seems like I will have to switch again.
To me it feels like a faulty hardware.